# why my session value alway present only after I refresh the page I also build session in playframework2?

Tags: scala, session, playframework-2.2

I use playframework2.2

I write session in one of my action:

```
def index = Action  {implicit rs =>
var newsession
if(currentUser.isDefined){
  val currentUser=SecureSocial.currentUser.get
 newsession= rs.session + ("user" -> currentUser.fullName)
}else{
newsession=rs.session
}

Ok(views.html.list_subject("Hello from Scala", sublist.run(DB.createSession()))).withSession(newsession)
}
```

on my list_subject page I use another template main :

```
@main(message) {
.....
}
```

in main.scala.html I use new session:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit request: RequestHeader)
....
....
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            @if(request.session.get("user").isDefined){
            ....
            }else {
                <li><a href="@securesocial.controllers.routes.LoginPage.login()">Login</a></li>
            }

        </ul>
```

I find the new session only work after the second time, I mean when I had already login the link login do not change, only after I refresh it then it changed. 
I also check the session by firebug and find only after the second the session will get by request. I want to know how the make the session change the first time (not need to refresh the page.)

Answer (score 0):

`withSession` will set a cookie that will provide the new session on following requests, it does not modify the current `RequestHeader` object. Your view does not have access to the changes made in the controller. You should modify your view so it takes the user as a parameter, rather than passing it the whole `RequestHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

> I find the new session only work after the second time

because you are using `Ok`

use

```
Redirect(path).withSession(newsession)//path is variable contaning the string to redirect
```

redirection is needed after cookie creation. then detected in browser so you have to redirect.

`Ok` , show your  different page in same page